# How to let the limited access dashboard partners to also add variants in django oscar

Tags: django, django-oscar

I have gone to the django-oscar dashboard and went to Fulfillment - > Partners, 
there I created a partner and linked a user and gave a limited dashboard access.

Now I see that most of the drop-downs are not visible to them(partner), that's fine.This is due to the permission given 'Can access dashboard'.

But, when I go to add the products, I see only the Stock and Pricing tab is there on the left, but there is no tab for variants, how do I get it to show in the dashboard of the partner also?
Should I give any other permission for the user linked ?

According to the docs link https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/ref/apps/dashboard.html in the `note` it says `The permission-based dashboard currently does not support parent or child products.Supporting this requires a modelling change. If you require this, please get in touch so we can first learn about your use case.` , but how and whom do I contact?

Or can I extend some of the partner views to achieve this?

Comment: you can contact them through raising an issue on their [Django-Oscar Github Repository](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/)